# Use natbib with alpha style

Tags: natbib

Is it possible to use `natbib` together with the `alpha` style? It doesn't seem to be supported directly in the `natbib` package. What I mean is that there is no specific `alpha`-like `natbib` style, and if I use `alpha` directly I lose the possibility of citing author names and such with `\citet`... Does anybody know of an `alpha` style that would work with `natbib`?

Comment: By "the alpha style", do you mean the style file `alpha.bst`, or do you mean some variant of author-year citation styles? If it's the former, he style file `plainnat.bst, which is distributed with `natbib`, should serve your needs. Separately, have you actually tried to use the `alpha` style file together with `natbib`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution using [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text about \citet{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but I have the same question and biblatex doesn't work with the journal style file I'm dealing with. So I would appreciate an answer that doesn't use biblatex.

Comment: Thx, this gave me the final impulse to switch to biblatex with the help of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5105/84434 and I am now happy with a more streamlined and elegant setup