# Getting problem when inserting natbib

Tags: citing, natbib

Currently, when displaying my references without `natbib`, it's appearing like

```
[Sin01]
```

and this is how I want it to be.

However, to get the `et al.` function, I'm having to include the `natbib` and change the bibliography style to `plainnat`. When doing this, I'm getting loads of problem.

My cite are turning like this `Singhal [2001]`.

Any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: You may have a look on the natbibmanual: ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf It is explained at the end of Section 2.7 and at the end of section 3.1. I tried to get it working but did not succeed. Also there was a similar question before. What you want to have is the `alpha`-citation style: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35306/use-natbib-with-alpha-style I hope this helps you.

Comment: is there any difference between biblatex and bibtex??

Comment: Yes there is. Natbib is using bibtex as its backend and compared to biblatex, natbib has some limitations, which become important in some cases, like proper footnote citations and some other stuff. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib for more info.

Comment: so if i understand, if I use biblatex, my citation cannot be of the same style as bibtex, i'll have to change the format of all my references?

Comment: `bibtex` (without "la") and `biber` are backends: applications which can process (sort) a bib file. `natbib` and `biblatex` (with "la") are LaTeX-packages. So one of your choice is to drop natbib+bibtex and use biblatex+biber or biblatex+bibtex instead. With biblatex+biber you will be able to get the style you want, but the change can take time. You can also continue to use natbib and try to find or create (with custom-bib) a suitable bibliography style.

Comment: i think its much more easier to write the et al manually then,