# My own publications list without natbib and biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, thesis, multibib

I am writing my PhD thesis and I should add the list of my own publication. I am not using `natbib` nor `biblatex`. Because with `natbib` I can't use the `alpha` style and `biblatex` is incompatible with the other packages I am using. I can only add a list that contains all my own publications but i need to divide them (journal papers and conference papers). I didn't find any solution to do this, my main tex is below and it works fine:

```
\documentclass[sommairechap,stylejchiquet]{these_gi}

\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{dk}{Liste des publications}

\begin{document}


\include{chap1/chap1}
\include{chap2/chap2} 
% ==================================================================
% CONCLUSION

\citedk{key}

\bibliographystyledk{alpha}

\bibliographydk{biblio}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35306/use-natbib-with-alpha-style

Comment: It's news to me that the `natbib` citation management package is supposed to be incompatible with the `alpha` bibliography style. Just don't use the `\citet` command; the command `\citep` works fine.

Comment: And (out of curiosity) which packages are you using that are incompatible?  Virtually every item on the incompatability list are bibliography-related and unnecessary since `biblatex` can do what they do already.

Comment: An unknown class file, no minimal working example. Talk of incompatibilities, never feedback. Right now, the question is unclear. You can improve it by clearing up the points i just mention. I vote to close.