# Changing citation style doesn't work

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

so I'm finishing up with my project and realized that I have to change the style of my citations to something like this:

```
% Biblatex {{{
\usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    %backref=true
    ]{biblatex}               % Biblatex mit alphabetischem Style und biber.
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % Dateiname der bib-Datei.
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{
    \mkbibemph{#1}}         % Make titles italics
% }}}
```

Which should produce something like this in the text:

[image: citation in the text]

Now I have been apparently working with a complete different solution which looks like this:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt,
  headings=small,
  parskip=half,      % Ersetzt manuelles setzten von parskip/parindent.
  bibliography=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot,    % Entfernt den letzten Punkt der Kapitelnummern.
  %open=any,        % Kapitel kann auf jeder Seite beginnen.
%  final          % Entfernt alle todonotes und den Entwurfstempel.
  ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=2.54cm,
  marginparwidth=2.0cm,
  footskip=1.0cm
  ]{geometry}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}

%%gegen möchliche Warnmeldungen bezüglich underfull \hbox wenn in der *.bbl file zu lange URLs sind
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\raggedright}{}{}

%   % fuer Literaturverweise
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{a}{}{;} % Natbib konfigurieren, so da� im text [M�ller 2006] erscheint und keine runden Klammern o.�.
    \renewcommand{\cite}{\citep} % \cite zu \citep umwandeln, so dass im Text \cite{Mueller.2006} f�r Referenzen verwendet werden kann.
%
%   %% Verhindert, dass im Literaturverzeichnis nach der Nennung von [Mueller 2006] die Seite umgebrochen wird und die Autoren + Buchtitel etc. auf der n�chsten Seite landen
%   %% Es wurde daher \noparagraphbreak in der natdin.bst bei der Ausgabe der Elemente erg�nzt
%   %% siehe http://groups.google.de/group/de.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/9ca4c681e2063fbd/f7eb3eec044b058e
    \makeatletter
    \def\noparagraphbreak{\interlinepenalty10000
     \@itempenalty-\@highpenalty}
    \makeatother 


\begin{document}
\newpage
\begin{singlespace}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\label{chap:Einleitung}
\end{singlespace}


Some text \citep[S.27-29{Magnusson2007}. 

\phantomsection % benötigt für korrekte pdf-darstellung
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{natdin} % Din 1505 nach Lorenzen (Das konkrete Aussehen des Litverzeichnisses ist im header festgelegt)
\interlinepenalty=10000 %sorgt dafür, dass Liteinträge nicht Seiten übergreifend sind
\bibliography{bibliography/library} % Pfad zur *.bib-Datei (Dateiendung wird weggelassen)

\end{document}
```

Which gives me citations in the text looking like this:

[image]

My problem is that I have tried to change it and simply use biblatex....but unfortunately I'm getting only errors....what am I missing?
Maybe its important to mention that I've been using the \citep[S.27-29]{some citation} command like this and have tried to include the pages where to find specific citations....

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: In your current set-up you use `natbib`, so you run BibTeX. With the `biblatex` code snippet you need to run Biber instead. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. A bit of background can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. You'll need to follow the steps in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864 if you want to use `biblatex`.

Comment: If you want to keep on using `\citep` (instead of `\parencite`) with `biblatex` you will also need to enable the `natbib` compatibility mode by adding `natbib=true` to the `biblatex` loading options.

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks for your reply I've tried to follow the steps for the last hours and am running in one problem after another e.g. miktex didnt have biber so I added it and updated the FNDB, then I tried to setup my TexStudio, but it just wasn't working....so i decided to go back to my old setting, which work just fine. ==> My question now is can I somehow use my current settings to make it look like the citation I actually would like to have?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35306/ suggests `natbib` does not have a compatible alphabetic style. The documentation says `natbib` is for author-year and numeric citation and does not mention alphabetic citations. But you can switch to `cite` and `alpha` style: `\documentclass{scrartcl}\usepackage{cite}\bibliographystyle{alpha}\begin{document}Lorem~\cite{sigfridsson}.\bibliography{mybibfile}\end{document}` I would, however, advise you to use `biblatex` and Biber. If you install Biber via MikTeX's package manager there should be no problem. What did you try exactly and how did it not work?

Comment: Hi moewe, Ok I tried it again....I installed the package using the miktex tool as suggested from you, this worked fine. Then I changed the code in my latex project adding the biblatex info and setting biber as background. I changed the settings in TexStudio as described to biber....==> first it compiled with an error "...bbl not created by bibtex..." or something like that....so i renamed the bbl file, but not it doesnt create a new one, doesnt set any citations and no bibliography

Comment: oh yeah and running the "compile bibliography" command (F8 in Texstudio) gives me this : Fehler: Eine Kommandoersetzung ungültig
    Eltern-Befehl: bibliography
    Hauptbefehl: bibliography

Comment: Can you make sure that Biber is actually installed and working? What do you get if you type `biber --version` in the command line? Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864. See also https://golatex.de/biblatex-gibt-fehlermeldungen-problem-mit-packageeinbindung-t18954.html

Comment: I get 2.11 as a result...biber seems to be installed and working

Comment: Good. Double check your settings against https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. What error do you get? Still the one about "ungültige Eltern-Befehle"? Try to compile the entire document from the command line (you seem to speak German, so have a  look at https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3461/wie-kompiliere-ich-in-der-eingabeaufforderung-im-terminal)

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to get Biber up and running?

Comment: Any news here? Could you get things going?

Comment: Any news here? It's been almost two weeks with no reaction now.